# Wordpress 5.0.3 - "Updating failed" and "Publishing failed". Console log shows a 404 on /blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1177/autosaves?_locale=user

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I updated Wordpress to the latest version (5.0.3). Now, any time I try to post I get a red message that says "Publishing failed". If I try to save a draft I get "Updating failed".

In console, I'm seeing

```
https://mydomain/com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1177/autosaves?_locale=user 404
```

When I test the URL with `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/` I get a 404. If i use `?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/` instead, I get my blog. I'm using Post name for permalinks.

Is there a way I can change the WordPress editor to use the rest route that is working? Or can I change something in my Nginx config?

Comment: While I don't think this is off-topic for SO, you may want to consider asking this in [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to close this anyways. I found the problem and it's very specific to my setup with little value to the community.

Comment: Use the classic editor plugin and switch back to Classic Editor. Gutenberg is shit as of now.

Comment: @Front_End_Dev Experiencing the same error - would you mind divulging what the issue was? I find setups are frequently not as rare as you'd think, and even where the minutiae of setup are different, the underlying cause of the issue is often the same.

Answer (score 2):

**two easy solutions:**

1. You should deactivate the security plugin, in my case problem was with Advanced Access Manager plugin that I deactivate it and problem fixed.
2. Use the Classic Editor plugin By WordPress Contributors, just install this plugin and use the Classic editor, here is the setting that you can use both **classic and block editor**.

   > Setting->Writing->Allow users to switch editors

then in the create page, you have this option

> For block editor => Switch to Classic Editor

[image]

> And Classic editor => Switch to Block Editor

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed my Permalink to Plain, then it's working, else it's throwing the same error!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this has something to do with permalinks and how url is rewritten. once I change my permalinks option to plain everything seems fine. I'm using a local install with nginx. hopefully will find out why this happens later.

Comment: This is not a proper answer. What you just wrote is a comment. Consider this for the future and read the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with WordPress 5.2.2. I couldn't save or publish a page (new or old). Although all requests in the page editor return 200 I realized that some requests had a request domain of my site and others a request domain of the hosting company. So, I went to **Settings** > **General** and changed the settings **Site Address (URL)** and **WordPress Address (URL)** to be the same value (I copied the value of Site Address (URL) into WordPress Address (URL)) and that fixed the problem with the editor.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Open the WordPress and login as administrator. When you post new content or older content you will be getting error message.

**Step 2**: So, now choose the older version of Editor of WordPress instead to use new version. To choose older version go to settings and then click on writings. Here you can find option "Classic Editor" and if you will not find option then choose second option.

This is one option but if you are not fixed with this option choose second option such as

Open the WordPress and on the left side you have list of tasks to be performed in WordPress. Click on the option “**Plugin**” and you will be opened with the plugin screen. On the top of the screen, you have the button “**add new**”.

**Step 3**: After clicking on the add new button, new screen will be opened. There, you can see classic editor plugin. Kindly, download and install it. Once it is installed, then activate it by clicking on the “**activate**” button.

**Step 4**: Again, go the Settings option and click on the Writing. In the Writing section, you have many options such as formatting, default post category, default post format, default editor for all users, allow users to switch editors, post via email etc.

Click on the classic editor choice in default editor for all users. This makes you to work easy on content posting newly or updating the previous contents.

Comment: this is one of the useful tips.

Comment: Try this way it is easy.

Comment: you can do it on the localhost also.

Answer (score 0):

With wp cli:

1. wp core update (get the latest version)
2. wp plugin update --all (why not update plug ins too)
3. wp plugin install classic-editor (get this)
4. wp plugin activate classic-editor (activate)

Answer (score 0):

When we get 404 in wordpress pages and publishing failed there could be an issue with .htaccess file.
Update your Permalink settings and check .htaccess file,  If .htaccess file is exist, and it's correct, confirm in your server .conf file have
Or your .htaccess file is not able to override server configuration

```
<Directory /var/www/web-app-wordpress>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart apache server after updating this code.